# Fixed flexbox to take up space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to find a modern solution to having a fixed menu bar (flex box) at the top of the page with a flex box underneath. I want the page to scroll with the menu to stay static and the content of the second content flex box to scroll (fixBox). However I want the fixed menu to act like it's relative with the fillBox div to appear below it and not underneath it....

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
      body {
         padding:0;
         margin:0;
      }
      #logo {
         width:170px;
         border: 1px solid black;
      }
      #menuStrip {
         position:relative;
         width:95%;
         height:100%;
         background-color:#f0f0f0;
         border: 1px solid black;
      }
      #topContainer {
         position:fixed;
         display: flex;
         justify-content: center;
         align-items: center;
         border: 1px solid black;
         width:100%;
         height:50px;
      }
      #fillBox {
         display:flex;
         justify-content: center;
         align-items: center;
         border: 1px solid black;
      }

      #fill1 {
         width:100%;
         height:2000px;
         background-color:#a2b565;
      }
      #menuObj {
         position:absolute;
         right:0;
         width:40px;
         height:30px;
         border:1px solid; black;
         background-color:red;

      }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="topContainer">
         <div id="menuStrip"><div id="menuObj"> </div></div>
      </div>
      <div id="fillBox">
         <div id="fill1"> <p> hello </p></div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hob3ckbc/)

NOTE: not looking for the top margin hack solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question has nothing to do with flexbox, it has to do with fixed positioning.

`position: fixed` takes DOM elements completely out of the flow of the document, so other DOM elements ignore the space they take up. One (of several possible) courses of action is to add a top padding to `#fillBox` that is equal to the height of `#topContainer` - if `#topContainer` will always have a fixed height.

```css
      body {
         padding:0;
         margin:0;
      }
      #logo {
         width:170px;
         border: 1px solid black;
      }
      #menuStrip {
         position:relative;
         width:95%;
         height:100%;
         background-color:#f0f0f0;
         border: 1px solid black;
      }
      #topContainer {
         position:fixed;
         display: flex;
         justify-content: center;
         align-items: center;
         border: 1px solid black;
         width:100%;
         height:50px;
      }
      #fillBox {
         padding-top: 50px;
         display:flex;
         justify-content: center;
         align-items: center;
         border: 1px solid black;
      }
         
      #fill1 {
         width:100%;
         height:2000px;
         background-color:#a2b565;
      }
      #menuObj {
         position:absolute;
         right:0;
         width:40px;
         height:30px;
         border:1px solid; black;
         background-color:red;
         
      }
```

```html
      <div id="topContainer">
         <div id="menuStrip"><div id="menuObj"> </div></div>
      </div>
      <div id="fillBox">
         <div id="fill1"> <p> hello </p></div>
      </div>
```

If `#topContainer` has a dynamic height, then you'll need to use JS on load/resize to set the top padding of `#fillBox` dynamically.

```js
    var $topContainer = $('#topContainer');
    var $fillBox = $('#fillBox');

    var updateTopBar = function() {
     var dynamicHeight = $topContainer.height();
     $fillBox.css({paddingTop:dynamicHeight+'px'});


    };

    $(window).on('load',updateTopBar).on('resize',updateTopBar);
```

```css
    body {
             padding:0;
             margin:0;
          }
          #logo {
             width:170px;
             border: 1px solid black;
          }
          #menuStrip {
             position:relative;
             width:95%;
             height:100%;
             background-color:#f0f0f0;
             border: 1px solid black;
          }
          #topContainer {
             position:fixed;
             display: flex;
             justify-content: center;
             align-items: center;
             border: 1px solid black;
             width:100%;
             height:50px;
          }
          

          #fillBox {
             display:flex;
             justify-content: center;
             align-items: center;
             border: 1px solid black;
          }
             
          #fill1 {
             width:100%;
             height:2000px;
             background-color:#a2b565;
          }
          #menuObj {
             position:absolute;
             right:0;
             width:40px;
             height:30px;
             border:1px solid; black;
             background-color:red;
             
          }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="topContainer">
       <div id="menuStrip"><div id="menuObj"> </div></div>
    </div>
    <div id="fillBox">
       <div id="fill1"> <p> hello </p></div>
    </div>
```